# Intermediate Value Theorem, min max or $f(a) f(b)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

I am interested in the Intermediate Value Theorem. According to school and some website, if $f(x)$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and $f(a)<L<f(b)$, there exists a value $c$ where $f(c) = L$. However, when I did some extensive search, more specifically Wikipedia, it said that even if $\min(f(a),f(b))<L<\max(f(a),f(b))$, a value $c$ also exists. So does the one on Wikipedia correct? I try to find more details on this but most of the website only states $f(a)<L<f(b)$. Please help!

Comment: If $f(a)>f(b)$, multiply by $-1$ and use the first version.

Comment: Try drawing a diagram to see what is going on. Diagrams can be dangerous for continuous functions, so don't over-rely on them (we tend to draw smoother functions than the typical continuous function) - but in this case it will help to build your intuition and help you to get a sense of the logical relationships involved. If you go from less to greater, you hit the value. If you go from greater to less, you hit the value - provided you have continuity, See $\sin \frac 1x$ and the Conway base $13$ function - in each case the intermediate value properties holds, but not continuity,

Comment: Elliot G's comment answers your particular question and you should try out @Mark Bennet's advice before reading on. $\cdots \cdots$ In fact, for the intermediate value theorem, i.e. (the satisfaction of the [intermediate value property](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_property) for continuous functions), you can state it as:
 If $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then for any $L$ satisfying $\min_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)\le L \le \max_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)$, you can find $c\in [a,b]$ satisfying $f(c)=L$.